# Configure network with two routers

Tags: networking

I have next home network structure:
[image]

From `PC1` I have access to `S1`.
The problem is that `TV1` can't see `DLNA` server with this configuration(I think it because `TV1` scan only it own IP range - `192.168.31.*`).
If I connect `S1` to `R1`, `TV1` will successfully find `DLNA`.

So, my question: Is it possible to grant addition IP by `R1` for `S1` connected to `M1`? Or is there any other solution to help `TV1` find `S1`?

PS: Connect `S1` to `R1` is not the case.

Comment: Why do you have this sort of frankensetup? Can you turn off NAT/DHCP in M1 and just use it as a switch, so that S1, TV1, and PC1 are all in the same subnet?

Comment: Because M1 is providers modem for Internet access and I think that if i turn off DHCP in M1, I'll lose internet connection. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @hdnn The box you're calling a modem is clearly more than a modem. It's a home gateway router with integrated modem functionality. It is capable of being the NAT gateway and DHCP server for your entire home network. So you don't want your Xiaomi Mi Router 3G doing those functions, because it breaks your network into two networks that have trouble communicating with each other.

Comment: @Spiff But I need Xiaomi Mi Router 3G as 5GHz Wi-Fi access point

Comment: You should still turn off NAT/DHCP in R1, then, so that S1, TV1, and PC1 are all on he same subnet. I have a similar physical setup at home, where my "R1" is a LinkSys WRT, and I've turned of NAT/DHCP so that it's acting as a WAP, but not a ROUTER.

Comment: When I turn off DHCP in M1 and run `sudo dhclient -r` in S1, I just lose connection to S1 because R1 doesn't give a new IP for S1

Comment: @hdnn I wasn't trying to say to get rid of your Xiaomi Mi Router 3G all togther, I was trying to say that you should put it into simple AP mode, so that it's just transparently bridging wireless traffic onto the LAN, and not trying to do NAT or be a DHCP server.

Comment: Yes, you both were right. Your advice helped. I had failed above because I also needed to switch ethernet connection in R1 from WAN port to LAN port